# Using gulp with google closure to compile js files into individual files instead of a single file

Tags: javascript, gulp, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I am using `google-closure-compiler` and gulp to minify my angularjs files.

I have the 3 js files in `app/js` folder. They are `controller.js, app.js, services.js`.

Here is my gulpfile code:

```
var closureCompiler = require('google-closure-compiler').gulp();

gulp.task('js-closure', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/js/*.js', {base: './'})
        .pipe(closureCompiler({
            compilation_level: 'SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS',
            warning_level: 'QUIET',
            language_in: 'ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT',
            language_out: 'ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT',
            output_wrapper: '(function(){\n%output%\n}).call(this)',
            js_output_file: 'output.min.js'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
});
```

What the code does is compile the 3 js files into a single file `output.min.js`

What I want is to compile the 3 js files into 3 separate js files `controller.min.js, app.min.js, services.min.js`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can see there's no way to avoid having your files combined by the Google Closure Compiler. Even if you leave out the `js_output_file` option it will simply default to the output file name `compiled.js`. That means you have to invoke the Closure Compiler for each file.

The `gulp-flatmap` plugin lets you do that easily. You just have to determine the value of `js_output_file` for each input file (basically replace `.js` with `.min.js` in each file name):

```
var flatmap = require('gulp-flatmap');
var path = require('path');

gulp.task('js-closure', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/js/*.js', {base: './'})
    .pipe(flatmap(function(stream, file) {
      return stream.pipe(closureCompiler({
        compilation_level: 'SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS',
        warning_level: 'QUIET',
        language_in: 'ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT',
        language_out: 'ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT',
        output_wrapper: '(function(){\n%output%\n}).call(this)',
        js_output_file: path.basename(file.path).replace(/js$/, 'min.js')
      }))
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tested that your answer works perfectly. Upvoted and selected as the right answer.

Comment: You can use code splitting to create separate output files, but it's not clear that this is the intent. For unrelated files, you need to invoke the compiler separately for each one (as this answer demonstrates).